# Web page (aspx) priority in search results

Tags: search, search-results

I have 3 files with same name

- default.jpg
- default.pdf
- default.aspx

I'm trying to create setting for search result which displays site pages (aspx) first.

Then renaming files like image, PDF etc.

Is it possible to make such changes in SharePoint search settings?

Please suggest something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If you are not satisfied with the search result ranking for specific
> queries, we recommend that you try to influence the ranking for those
> queries with query rules. In most cases, configuring query rules will
> help you reach your goals, and you won't have to consider changing the
> context of a managed property or creating a custom ranking model.
>
> For each query rule, you can influence the way you sort, rank and
> display search results. Each query rule consists of a query rule
> condition and a query rule action. Whenever a query matches a query
> rule condition, the query rule action that you specify in the query
> rule triggers.

...

> ## Dynamic ordering: promote or demote search results.
>
> You can dynamically change the ranking of search results. You can specify when
> you want to change the ranking of the search results for a query, and
> by how much, when a certain condition applies. The following table
> shows the conditions that you can set.

In your case, you could match if the result is of the content type is a Page or Site Page. Another option would be to Match if the result URL exactly matches the specified URL, in your case the `.aspx`.

So its definately doable.

Reference: [Overview of search result ranking in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169065.aspx#Ranking_QueryRules)

Comment: Let me try this.